# The requested URL was not found on this server [in build]. react + vite

Tags: reactjs, build, http-status-code-404, vite

I have a multi-site that displays a menu for more than one restaurant. It relies on Menu ID to fetch data from the server by using params. It works well during the creation phase, but when I upload the project, I get this problem. The requested URL was not found on this server.

router.jsx

```
import { createBrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Root from "./Root";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import View from "./pages/View";
import ErrorPage from "./pages/ErrorPage";
import ContactUs from "./pages/ContactUs";
import AboutUs from "./pages/AboutUs";
import Cart from "./pages/Cart";
import ContactMdl from "./pages/ContactMdl";

export const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/:menuId",
    element: <Root />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
    children: [
      {
        index: true,
        element: <Home />,
      },
      {
        path: "view",
        element: <View />,
      },
      {
        path: "contactus",
        element: <ContactUs />,
      },
      {
        path: "contactus/done",
        element: <ContactMdl />,
      },
      {
        path: "aboutus",
        element: <AboutUs />,
      },
      {
        path: "cart",
        element: <Cart />,
      },
    ],
  },
]);
```

Root.jsx

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { Toaster } from "react-hot-toast";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Outlet, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useGetInformationQuery } from "./store/apis/basicInformation";
import { setMenuId } from "./store/slices/menuIdSlice";

function Root() {
  const { MENU_ID } = useSelector((state) => state.menuIdSlice);
  const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cartSlice);
  const { data } = useGetInformationQuery(MENU_ID);
  let { menuId } = useParams();
  const { i18n } = useTranslation();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("MENU_ID", menuId);
    dispatch(setMenuId(menuId));
  }, [dispatch, menuId]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Update title
    document.title =
      i18n.language == "ar" ? data?.ar_business_name : data?.en_business_name;

    // Update favicon
    const favicon = document.querySelector("link[rel~='icon']");
    if (favicon) {
      favicon.href = `https://backend.skilltax.sa/public/${data?.logo}`;
    }
  }, [data, i18n.language]);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cart));
  }, [cart]);

  useEffect(() => {
    document.documentElement.setAttribute("dir", i18n.dir());
    document.documentElement.setAttribute("lang", i18n.language);
  }, [i18n, i18n.language]);

  return (
    <div className="w-full max-w-[480px] mx-auto min-h-screen h-full relative">
      <Toaster
        position="top-center"
        reverseOrder={false}
        toastOptions={{ duration: 1500 }}
      />
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Root;
```

I have an MENU_ID to fetch all the data